# How can I match any character in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I would like to match any character in the range \u0000 to \uFFFF, the following code is not sufficient:

```
grammar CharacterClass;

start   :       CH* EOF;
CH      :       [\u0000-\uFFFF];
```

**Edit:**

I'm asking, because I want to insert binary data in a XML like structure:

```
<binary:key>uhihahdudi    some binary data, that should be ignored by ANTLR
izgizgio</binary:key>
```

Sure it is possible to restrict myself to the range [\u0000-\u00FF] and my Inputstream only outputs byte values of the processed data, but then I would have to implement extra logic to use my actual text-data.

The best solution for me would be, that ANTLR skips the binary parts somehow, so I can process the text data (to process the binary parts I would only need the beginning and end positions of these parts);

Answer (score 4):

ANTLR 4 is only able to match the range `[\u0000-\uFFFE]`. If you truly need to match all possible inputs, you'll need to match `[\u0000-\u00FF]` and feed the input to your parser as bytes instead of UTF-16 characters.

Edit: also see the [`Lexer.MIN_CHAR_VALUE` and `Lexer.MAX_CHAR_VALUE`](http://antlr.org/api/Java/constant-values.html#org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer.MAX_CHAR_VALUE) constants.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution is a good idea, but it is not my prefered solution. Could you look at my question again, I gave a more detailed description of my problem. (I do not want to process binary data, but I want to insert it in a xml like structure. I only need to skip these binary parts somehow with ANTLR)